# Странная работа NaN в python: nan != nan and [nan] == [nan]

Tags: python, float

Есть такой код:

```
a = float("nan")
a == a              # Получаем False
[a] == [a]          # Получаем True
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что в первом случае работает свойство NaN.

А во втором случае Python проверяет на равенство **массивы**, а не объекты `a`.

В данном случае `[a] == [a]` - объекты внутри массивов одни и те же (один и тот же экземпляр класса), а следовательно Python будет реагировать на `a` как на обычные объекты (сначала сравнивать по ссылкам).

Answer (score 8):

Здесь есть некоторая несогласованность.

С одной стороны, в CPython, `nan != nan` возвращает значение, которое Си на данной системе возвращает для `nan` — [`float_richcompare()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3d4dbd8f019c0bbac99fc9248077044ff1039ca3/Objects/floatobject.c#L333-L527):

> Python x == y delivers the same result as the platform
>     C x == y when x and/or y is a NaN.

что означает IEEE 754 поведение как правило: [NaN не равен даже самому себе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0).

С другой стороны, сравнение элементов списков, использует сравнение, которое сперва проверяет ссылаются ли параметры на один и тот же объект, не вызывая операцию равенства (`a==b`) для случая `a is b`— [`PyObject_RichCompareBool()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3d4dbd8f019c0bbac99fc9248077044ff1039ca3/Objects/object.c#L711-L737):

> Quick result when objects are the same.  Guarantees that identity implies equality.

Поэтому `[nan] == [nan]` (так как `nan is nan`), не смотря на то, что `nan != nan`.

Формально, [Питон (вне зависимости от реализации) гарантирует](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons), что `x == x` ложно для  `x = float('NaN')`, но внутри коллекции такой как список `x == x` всегда считается истинно:

> the comparison of collections assumes that for a collection element x, x == x is always true.